# Filtering a ReactiveCocoa Signal Using Values As Well As the Current Date

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have two signals of `Event` objects. `Event` objects have a `date` property, which is set to the date the event was created. The two signals send events as they are created.

I want to create a third signal which:

- when `event2.date` falls within 1 second on either side of `event1.date`, send a tuple containing both events
- when 1 second passes after the most recent `event1.date`, and the most recent `event2`'s `date` does not fall within the valid range, send a tuple containing only `event1`

I'm using `combineLatest:` and `filter` to create a signal which filters the tuples using the first criteria:

```c
[[RACSignal combineLatest:@[ signal1, signal2 ]]
    filter:^BOOL(RACTuple *tuple) {
        RACTupleUnpack(Event *event1, Event *event2) = tuple;

        NSDate *startDate = [event1.date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1];
        NSDate *endDate = [event1.date dateByAddingTimeInterval:1];

        if ([event2.date compare:startDate] == NSOrderedAscending) return NO;
        if ([event2.date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending) return NO;

        return YES;
    }];
```

How can I make a signal which incorporates both criteria?

Comment: I'm not certain it would help here, but have you looked at [`-bufferWithTime:onScheduler:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L137)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your requirements, but are the two criteria inverses of each other? In other words, are you saying that a value sent on either `signal1` or `signal2` will always result in either a `(event1)` or an `(event1, event2)` being sent? I ask because if so, you could just change your `-filter:` to a `-map:` and then replace the `NO` booleans with the former (tuple of just `event1`), and replace the `YES` boolean with the latter (tuple of `event1` and `event2`).

Comment: From my reading of the question, you've got the solution, @erikprice.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. Each value sent on `signal1` will result in one value being sent on the new signal, either `(event1)` or `(event1, event2)`, depending on if there is an value from `signal2` that meets the criteria. I think I have a working solution now which I will post shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me, although I'm not sure if it's the most elegant solution.

`signal2` is multicast using a `RACReplaySubject` with a capacity of `1` in order to be able to get the last value from that signal even if it occurred before the most recent value from `signal1`.

```c
[[signal1
    map:^RACSignal *(Event *event1) {
        RACSignal *interval = [[[RACSignal interval:RemoteTimeAfter onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
            map:^id(id value) {
                return RACTuplePack(event1);
            }]
            take:1];

        RACSignal *filteredSignal2 = [[signal2
            filter:^BOOL(Event *event2) {
                NSDate *startDate = [event.date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1];
                NSDate *endDate = [event.date dateByAddingTimeInterval:1];

                if ([event2.date compare:startDate] == NSOrderedAscending) return NO;
                if ([event2.date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending) return NO;

                return YES;
            }]
            map:^RACTuple *(Event *event2) {
                return RACTuplePack(event1, event2);
            }];

        return [[RACSignal merge:@[ interval, filteredSignal2 ]] take:1];
    }]
    flatten];
```